# Cómo almacenar datos de un formulario que se registran al mismo tiempo

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-hoja-de-cálculo

Tengo algo de conocimiento de programación y tengo la siguiente duda con un formulario que estoy desarrollado con *Javascript*, en *Google Apps Script*, y almacena la data en *Google Sheets*, específicamente en una hoja. El formulario es usado por varios usuarios. El inconveniente es que cuando los usuarios registran la información en el mismo instante, sólo se llega a guardar uno de ellos.

La lógica de insertar en la data en las filas de la hoja es validar cual es la última celda con data, e insertar la información en la siguiente fila vacía. Pero si los usuarios dan click al botón guardar en el mismo instante, este les devuelve la misma celda vacía, y al final solo se llega a guardar el registro de uno de ellos. He intentado buscar en *Google* pero no conozco el término con el cual buscar. Agradecería alguna ayuda.

Answer (score 0):

La solución es simple y directa, en lugar de usar cualquiera de las variantes de `getRange` usa el método `appendRow` de la clase Sheet.

En ciertos casos podría ser más conveniente usar el Lock Service pero esto añade complejidad y posiblemente riesgos. Complejidad porque deberás determinar un tiempo apropiado de espera y así como la forma de manejar los casos en que dicho tiempo de espera se exceda.

Recursos

- https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets
- https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#appendRow